# How to calculate mean, median and mode from a set of CONTINUOUS numbers in Java?

Tags: java, mode, median, continuous, mean

Do you know if there is a library that supports these statistical operations or a way to do it in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no library methods in java to achieve this. Please read this similar topic

[Mean, Median, Mode, Range - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121188/mean-median-mode-range-java)