# Get median from array

Tags: java, arrays, median

I am trying to get the median length from my array. I am using the following code but I get errors. I do not know why I get these errors.

```
int middleSlot = list.length/2;
    list[middleSlot];
```

Comment: HashSet is stored using a hash function and its not linear allocation like an Array. You cannot achieve what you want by what you are doing.

Comment: Is it a Set a list or an array???

Comment: @Alboz i believe its an HashSet as per the question.

Comment: @wrongAnswer I know but he calls it "list" for some weird reasons..

Comment: Hello everyone. I am taking lessons and a HashSet falls under a SET. I called my HashSet as "list" I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: No you didn't. `list` is clearly an array, not a HashSet, or set of any kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Commons Math will do it.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html#a1.3_Frequency_distributions

OR:
[Mean, Median, Mode, Range - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121188/mean-median-mode-range-java)

> USAGE would be:   `double answer = getMean(list);`

**getMean()**

```
public double getMean(double[] numberList) {
    double total;
    for (double d: numberList) {
        total += d;
    }
    return total / (numberList.length);
}
```

**getMedian()**

```
This method is going on the assumption that the passed array is already sorted (i.e. {1,2,3,...}).

public double getMedian(double[] numberList) {
    int factor = numberList.length - 1;
    double[] first = new double[(double) factor / 2];
    double[] last = new double[first.length];
    double[] middleNumbers = new double[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
        first[i] = numbersList[i];
    }
    for (int i = numberList.length; i > last.length; i--) {
        last[i] = numbersList[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberList.length; i++) {
        if (numberList[i] != first[i] || numberList[i] != last[i]) middleNumbers[i] = numberList[i];
    }
    if (numberList.length % 2 == 0) {
        double total = middleNumbers[0] + middleNumbers[1];
        return total / 2;
    } else {
        return middleNumbers[0];
    }
}
```

**getMode()**

```
public double getMode(double[] numberList) {
    HashMap<Double,Double> freqs = new HashMap<Double,Double>();
    for (double d: numberList) {
        Double freq = freqs.get(d);
        freqs.put(d, (freq == null ? 1 : freq + 1));   
    }
    double mode = 0;
    double maxFreq = 0;    
    for (Map.Entry<Double,Doubler> entry : freqs.entrySet()) {     
        double freq = entry.getValue();
        if (freq > maxFreq) {
            maxFreq = freq;
            mode = entry.getKey();
        }
    }    
    return mode;
}
```

**getRange()**

```
public double getRange(double[] numberList) {
    double initMin = numberList[0];
    double initMax = numberList[0];
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberList.length; i++) {
        if (numberList[i] < initMin) initMin = numberList[i];
        if (numberList[i] > initMax) initMax = numberList[i];
    }
    return initMax - initMin;
}
```

Comment: For the median method; What if the arrays is a hash set? Will it ignore it and still run the method?

Comment: How would you call this method from main? for example if I call a method that returns void I would use "myMethod();" How would you call this method to run? Perhaps like: "getMedian(double,list);" ??

Comment: > USAGE would be:   `double answer = getMean(list);`

Answer (score 0):

To get the element in the middle you might want to do something like

```
int middleSlot = list.size()/2;
int counter =0 ;
TypeOfList middleElement=null;
for(TypeOfList eachElement: list.values) {
   if(counter == middleSlot) {
       middleElement= eachElement; break;
   }
   counter++;
}
```